# How to create dummy fields

Tags: 7

I use Drupal7. I want to create some dozens of dummy fields in my test node quickly. But, it will take long if I do at "manage fields page"(admin/structure/types/manage/CONTENT_TYPE).

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any modules to do it(Devel Generat can create contents, but not fields). Any suggestions to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/bundle_copy

1. Create a field
2. Export the bundle/content type
3. Copy the field in the exported text, paste several times, changing stuff for each field that you want to change for each new field
4. Import the same bundle/content type

Comment: Hi Emil, Thank you for your answer.
Yes, this worked! Actually, I did it with a combination with excel, replacing those stuffs in effective way. Thank you so much!